# Deque<E> added in API level 9, no compile error or warning for api level 8 project

Tags: android, compilation

I'm havin problem with `Deque<E>`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Deque.html

The page says: **Added in API level 9**

but I'm compiling my Android project with:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

without any error or warning. **I'm using Android 2.3.3 (Api 9)** library for my project as you can see here:

[image]

**Why no compile or Lint warning/error?**

Comment: You're using Library for API level 9, hence it compiles.  Replace it with API level 8 - and you should see the error.

Comment: That's ok, I'm wondering why I get no compiler/Lint message

Comment: Check this out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782749/checking-for-violations-of-androidminsdkversion-automatically)

Comment: You're not getting any errors exactly because your library is API level 9. When the build process occurs, it only checks against the library you selected.

Comment: So it's a normal behaviour. I did a mistake, but why is it possible to have android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" and the build library Api 9?

Comment: Versions in manifest have no impact on your library selection.  They are used for device filtering when you upload the app to google play.  When you first set up the project, eclipse wizard asks you for the version and puts it into the manifest as well as selects the library for you.  After that, changing the version in the manifest won't automatically change your library, you'll need to do it yourself.

Comment: Having android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" and the build library Api 9 make no sense to me. Or are there any case where it's useful?